# Issue with push notification using cron in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, push-notification

I am trying to perform push notification activitiy using a cron within Google App Engine. I have setup the cron successfully and it is showing no failures. Also in logs i see that Multicasts are being created for all devices which are registered. However i am not getting any push notifications. Same code if i change using a form for sending Push notifications, its working perfectly fine. Can someone guide me on what can be the issue?

**Update**

Below is the form i have created where i send a POST request via form. This form takes the Message from Text area and sends it to all devices.

```
      out.print("<form name='form' method='POST' action='sendAll'>");
      out.print("<fieldset>");
      out.print("<textarea rows='10' cols='100' name='Message'>Enter HTML Message </textarea>");
      out.print("</fieldset>");
      out.print("<input type='submit' value='Send Message' />");
      out.print("</form>");
```

When i replace them with a normal post request which reads out the message from Data folder using below code,

```
 getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/sendAll").forward(req, resp);
```

i get success messages in GCM Logs but doesnt receive any push notification. Can someone guide on what can be the issue?

Comment: so the same code outside a cron works?

Comment: You should provide more insight on your operation, we don't even know the technology used for notifications! Code is very useful too.

Comment: added further information. On checking GCM logs, observed that Multicast messages are getting stored but are not sent.

Answer (score 0):

It was nothing specific to Google App Engine. Message which was created for push notifications had issue.